# Why slick slides drop all list of items in the middle and after pressing the arrow everything working how it should be?

Tags: slick.js

Why slick slides drop all list of items in the middle and after pressing the arrow everything working how it should be??[pic on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUva6.jpg)     [pic after pressing next button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geHpY.jpg)

Comment: Please look at the `slick` tag that you applied; it doesn't seem to have anything to do with a user interface. Please apply appropriate tags, and add relevant code.

Comment: but when why everything working after pressing the arrow?? just on load drops everything in the middle.